# displaying funnel chart using flot.js and data source as external json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts, flot

i am trying to plot a funnel chart using flot.js library ,taking an external json file as input but although the json is fetched it is not working as a datasource and the chart is not being plotted.
guys i have a json file SAMPLE.JSON

```
[
  {
    "data": 10,
    "label": "a"
  },
  {
    "data": 81,
    "label": "b"
  },
  {
    "data": 20,
    "label": "c"
  },
  {
    "data": 90,
    "label": "d"
  }
]
```

but it not working as a datasource for the Plot function of the folt.js library

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Flot Examples: Funnel Charts</title>
    <link href="css/examples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flot.funnel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
      var data;
      $.getJSON("sample.json", function(json) {
      data=json;
      console.log(data);
      });

      var placeholder = $("#placeholder");
          $.plot('#placeholder', data, {
              series:{
                funnel: {
                      show: true,
                    stem: {
                        height: 0.2,
                        width: 0.4
                    },
                    margin: {
                        //right: 0.15
                    },
                    label:{
                        show: true,
                        align: "center",
                        threshold: 0.05,
                        formatter: labelFormatter
                    },
                    highlight: {
                        opacity: 0.2
                    }
                },
            },
            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true
            }
        });

        placeholder.bind("plotclick", function(event, pos, obj) {
            if (!obj) {
                return;
            }
            alert(obj.series.label + ": " + obj.series.value);
        });

        function labelFormatter(label, series) {
            return "<div style='font-size:11pt; text-align:center; padding:2px; color:#fff;'>"+series.value+"</div>";
        }

    });


    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="header">
        <h2 style='text-align:center'>Funnel Charts</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="content">

        <h3 id="title"></h3>
        <div class="demo-container">
            <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder" style="length:250px,width:250px"></div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is in the wrong format. From the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/danielpes/flot-funnel#data-structure), the expected data format is (your data isn't in an array of arrays):

```
var data = [
    {
        label: "a",
        data: [ [ 1, 10 ] ]
    },  
    {   
        label: "b",
        data: [ [ 1, 81 ] ]
    },  
    {   
        label: "c",
        data: [ [ 1, 20 ] ]
    },  
    {   
        label: "d",
        data: [ [ 1, 90 ] ]
    }
];
```

This [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8ehfxq8/) has a working example of a funnel chart with your data.